# Html code broke when shiny upgraded to bootstrap 3

Tags: html, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

When Shiny upgraded to bootstrap 3, some of my programs looked wonky as a result. So I used [shinybootstrap2](https://github.com/rstudio/shinybootstrap2) for backward compatibility.  Unfortunately, there's still a chunk of code that's not being displayed properly (see column **Link** in the snapshot below). Before the upgrade, this column used to display hyperlinks which take the user to an external website upon clicking. However, now they are just being displayed as text and do not behave interactively. Here's the code I used to populate the column:

```
paste('<a href = ', shQuote(url), '>', 'Click</a>')
```

the `url` is just another variable where the actual link address is stored.

Any clue/thoughts as to why this might be happening?

[image: snapshot]

Comment: FYI, in the long terms, we will remove DataTables functions from shiny, and switch to DT: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to allow parsing of links...

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
  get_table()
},escape=FALSE)
```

Or escape individual columns as indicated in the [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html)

Comment: I'm using `renderDataTable()` though as you can see above.

Comment: I didn't see any code in your question, my bad... I've edited my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: magic!! I didn't actually have to use `get_table()`. the `escape` argument did the job. Just curious, does this only work with bootstrap2? I'd like to see if this would have fixed my code without having to do backward compatibility.

Comment: @BahaeOmid It is just a coincidence. We changed renderDataTable() and Bootstrap at the same time. Bootstrap is irrelevant here. Correlation is not causation :)

Comment: Oh I see. May I ask why DataTables are to be phased out in the future? Is this going to cause a substantial effort to change existing code relying on DataTables?